# Hibernate Envers Timestamp from revision date

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate-envers

I'm using MySQL and Hibernate Envers to log audity info, it saves a timestamp in a numeric format, how can i convert this timestamp to date in MySQL, not in Java?

[image]

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE -**

You can use `FROM_UNIXTIME()` in-built function.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_from-unixtime

Simply taking it into Date object, it should work -

```
Date date = resultSet.getTimestamp("timestamp");
```

Comment: I guess i didn't explicit it in the top, i'll edit it, the problem is to convert timestamp in the MySQL.

Answer (score 0):

I guess this timestamp includes milliseconds, so you can simply divide this value by 1000 :

```
FROM_UNIXTIME(hr.`TIMESTAMP`/1000)
```

Formatted:

```
DATE(FROM_UNIXTIME(hr.`TIMESTAMP`/1000))
OR
DATE_FORMAT(FROM_UNIXTIME(hr.`TIMESTAMP`/1000) ,'%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s')
```